# SceneKit - How to know if SCNNode with MDLObject is loaded and visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

i have a problem with animating SCNNode "on rendered", so my question is how to know that SCNNode is fully loaded and visible on scene ? I want to animate its scale right after load/render.

Here's how i initialize it:

```
NSString* ring = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                 pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sweep"]
                 ofType:@"obj"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ring];

MDLAsset *asset = [[MDLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url];
self.node = [SCNNode nodeWithMDLObject:[asset objectAtIndex:0]];
self.node.geometry.firstMaterial = goldMaterial;
self.node.geometry.subdivisionLevel = 1;

[self.node setRotation:SCNVector4Make(-1, 0, 0, M_PI/2.5)]; //M_PI = 180d
[self.node setScale:SCNVector3Make(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)];
[scene.rootNode addChildNode: self.node];
```

and right after that i tried to add action like this

```
SCNAction *scaleUp = [SCNAction scaleTo:1.0f duration:0.5f];
scaleUp.timingMode = SCNActionTimingModeEaseInEaseOut;
[self.node runAction:scaleUp];
```

but my node just shows scaled up, because it takes like ~2s to load obj asset.
When i change duration to like 5s, i can see animation.

I also tried to delegate SCNSceneRenderer: didRenderScene, but i also couldn't run that animation succesfuly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lucky. I am dealing with this topic recently. Assume you are using a SCNView as the SCNSceneRender, you can add the rootNode to the following call and then in completion callback handle other operations, like this:

```
 // setup everything here. It's your code.

 NSString* ring = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
             pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sweep"]
             ofType:@"obj"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ring];

MDLAsset *asset = [[MDLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url];
self.node = [SCNNode nodeWithMDLObject:[asset objectAtIndex:0]];
self.node.geometry.firstMaterial = goldMaterial;
self.node.geometry.subdivisionLevel = 1;

[self.node setRotation:SCNVector4Make(-1, 0, 0, M_PI/2.5)]; //M_PI = 180d
[self.node setScale:SCNVector3Make(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)];
 [scene.rootNode addChildNode: self.node];
SCNAction *scaleUp = [SCNAction scaleTo:1.0f duration:0.5f];
scaleUp.timingMode = SCNActionTimingModeEaseInEaseOut;

 [self.node runAction:scaleUp];




SCNView * view; // you don't need this if you have one already.
[view prepareObjects:@[scene.rootNode] withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success)   {
    if(success) {
        //scene will be rendered after this point.
    }
}];
```

Hope it's what you need.

Comment: thanks, that's what i needed :) i even had this part, but forgot about if(success) after couple hours of frustration :)